# Handling Pinch Zoom

Tags: android, android-studio, pinchzoom

I've a class which extends `Fragment`. I'm trying to perform pinch zoom. But its not working. I've tried every single piece of code but its not working.
I don't get any error in the output no debugger error its just the thing it doesn't work when we try to expand it from our fingers remains intact.
My xml file goes like that :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/mypic"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and the Testing Map activity goes like that :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener{


private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
private ImageView imageView;
private float scale = 1f;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(),new ScaleListener());
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}


private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale  = scale*detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale = Math.max(0.1f,Math.min(scale,5.0f));
        matrix.setScale(scale,scale);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
}}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by isn't working? what behaviour do you have? do you get any debugger error output?

Comment: This looks like Android. You should include which language(s) & SDK(s) you're using in the tags.

Comment: I don't get any error neither it gets expanded when we try to  enlarge/zoom it from our fingers. The picture remains intact no change.

Comment: Add the correct tags to the question as BSMP says, and your question will get more visibility amongst experts in the relevant areas - people cannot answer your question if they cannot find it based on their interests!